# Is there another way to load data in to the Bing Heat Map Creator than uploading a CSV?

Tags: bing-maps, bing, bing-api

I was looking at the Bing Heat Map Creator [here](http://www.bing.com/maps/explore/?catalogName=4a303e85_HeatMapCreatorJune03#5003/0.60303=/5872/style=auto&lat=47.6805&lon=-122.120941&z=11&pid=5874). 
It looks pretty cool, but I wanted to build something a little more dynamic with it.  Unfortunately it appears as if the only way to use it is by uploading a CSV file manually.  Does anyone know of another way to get the data loaded into this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We developed the Bing Heat Map Creator, which is a Map App running on the Bing Maps platform. It is certainly possible to build similar heat mapping features in a more automated mapping application but likely would not be done as a map app due to limitations with map apps APIs. Ping me if you want to discuss further.

Regards
Steve